# tikzpictures side by side with downscaling

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats

How can i get two tikzpictures in one figure using subfigure and scale them down a bit such that they fit the page? If it fits anyways, not downscaling needs to be done.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,bibtotoc,idxtotoc,headsepline,footsepline,footexclude,BCOR12mm,DIV13]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[h]{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[legend pos=north west]
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000043)(10000000,0.000208)(100000000,0.001435)(1000000000,0.024813)(10000000000,0.052237)(100000000000,0.392075)(1000000000000,7.640320)};
        \addlegendentry{Eigen Sparse};
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000038)(10000000,0.000102)(100000000,0.000687)(1000000000,0.004481)(10000000000,0.039102)(100000000000,0.473834)(1000000000000,4.163624)};
        \addlegendentry{Eigen Dense};
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000250)(10000000,0.002253)(100000000,0.023046)(1000000000,0.226521)(10000000000,2.256439)(100000000000,22.539281)(1000000000000,228.897577)};
        \addlegendentry{Taco Sparse};
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000164)(10000000,0.001970)(100000000,0.019437)(1000000000,0.193552)(10000000000,2.324910)(100000000000,22.873258)(1000000000000,228.062183)};
        \addlegendentry{Taco Dense};
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h]{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[legend pos = north west]
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000006)(10000000,0.000021)(100000000,0.000191)(1000000000,0.001376)(10000000000,0.014545)(100000000000,0.152963)(1000000000000,3.680731)};
        \addlegendentry{Eigen Sparse};
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000037)(10000000,0.000126)(100000000,0.001479)(1000000000,0.012454)(10000000000,0.085147)(100000000000,1.099040)(1000000000000,9.001991)};
        \addlegendentry{Eigen Dense};
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000066)(10000000,0.000474)(100000000,0.004661)(1000000000,0.047827)(10000000000,0.448608)(100000000000,4.491783)(1000000000000,47.770237)};
        \addlegendentry{Taco Sparse};
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000324)(10000000,0.004057)(100000000,0.040353)(1000000000,0.428903)(10000000000,4.614751)(100000000000,46.221847)(1000000000000,462.256123)};
        \addlegendentry{Taco Dense};
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{This is the plot for Sparse vs Dense implementations with a sparsity of 95\% and 99\%}
\label{plot:SparseVSDense}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This should not look like this:
[image: fail]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your figure is to wide and you didn't load any package that provides a `subfigure` environment. Once one fixes this, one gets

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,bibtotoc,idxtotoc,headsepline,footsepline,footexclude,BCOR12mm,DIV13]{scrbook}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[legend pos=north west,width=0.99\textwidth]
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000043)(10000000,0.000208)(100000000,0.001435)(1000000000,0.024813)(10000000000,0.052237)(100000000000,0.392075)(1000000000000,7.640320)};
        \addlegendentry{Eigen Sparse};
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000038)(10000000,0.000102)(100000000,0.000687)(1000000000,0.004481)(10000000000,0.039102)(100000000000,0.473834)(1000000000000,4.163624)};
        \addlegendentry{Eigen Dense};
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000250)(10000000,0.002253)(100000000,0.023046)(1000000000,0.226521)(10000000000,2.256439)(100000000000,22.539281)(1000000000000,228.897577)};
        \addlegendentry{Taco Sparse};
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000164)(10000000,0.001970)(100000000,0.019437)(1000000000,0.193552)(10000000000,2.324910)(100000000000,22.873258)(1000000000000,228.062183)};
        \addlegendentry{Taco Dense};
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}~
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[legend pos = north west,width=0.99\textwidth]
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000006)(10000000,0.000021)(100000000,0.000191)(1000000000,0.001376)(10000000000,0.014545)(100000000000,0.152963)(1000000000000,3.680731)};
        \addlegendentry{Eigen Sparse};
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000037)(10000000,0.000126)(100000000,0.001479)(1000000000,0.012454)(10000000000,0.085147)(100000000000,1.099040)(1000000000000,9.001991)};
        \addlegendentry{Eigen Dense};
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000066)(10000000,0.000474)(100000000,0.004661)(1000000000,0.047827)(10000000000,0.448608)(100000000000,4.491783)(1000000000000,47.770237)};
        \addlegendentry{Taco Sparse};
        \addplot coordinates {(1000000,0.000324)(10000000,0.004057)(100000000,0.040353)(1000000000,0.428903)(10000000000,4.614751)(100000000000,46.221847)(1000000000000,462.256123)};
        \addlegendentry{Taco Dense};
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{This is the plot for Sparse vs Dense implementations with a sparsity of 95\% and 99\%}
\label{plot:SparseVSDense}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This assumes you want eventually to give the subfigures captions. If not, or if you want to give them titles instead, you may want to use the `groupplots` library.

Comment: Sry, subcaptions is used, i just forgot to add it.

Comment: And by the way, it now works perfectly. Thank you a lot

Comment: @CleboSevic You're welcome!